# After upgrading android studio to Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 getting this gradle issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Plugin [id: 'com.android.library', version: '7.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.library', version: '7.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:7.2.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Google
  MavenRepo
  at

org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:221)

at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)

If someone has resolved this, please let me know, Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue, this is ridiculous from a company like Google... Just use the 7.2.0-rc02

Comment: i have the same issue facing when upgrading gradle. but the above mentioned solution is not working for me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess AGP7.2.0 hasn't been uploaded to Maven yet? [Maven page of Android Application Gradle Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin)

I solved this problem temporarily by setting the Android Gralde plugin version to 7.2.0-rc02 in the Android Studio/Project Structure/Project.

Comment: I ran into this issue yesterday and that's what I did. I was keeping an eye on [Google's Maven repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.tools.build:gradle) and 7.2.0 just appeared minutes ago. Updated it in the build file and it works now.

Comment: yes now the 7.2.0 is available, thanks for your remind.

Comment: After Rebuilding and Invalidating Caches, 7.2.0 is still not working for me.

Comment: you found any way?

Comment: sorry that i didn't come into trouble when upgrade to 7.2.0. and just now 7.2.1 is released, maybe you can have a try?

Answer (score 2):

Android Gradle plugin version 7.2.0 has been uploaded to Maven. Now we can use id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false

Answer (score 0):

you should update android gradle plugin version to 7.2.1 , and gradle version to 7.3.3

you can edit versions by

> file->projectstructure->project
> and make changes